# How can I use variables from a for loop from another class?

Tags: java, class, for-loop, row

In my code, my for loops iterates through my array of type list and indices an integer.

I need to grab the contents of said integer from another class to execute some code.

```
for (row = 0; row < myEntries.size(); row++)
```

And from a click of a button in my other class will be:

```
System.out.println(myEntries.get(row).toString());
```

Which will then print out the contents of a certain row I'd have already specified.

Since my code is inside a for loop, and I need to get the contents of a row from another class, how do I go about doing this?

Thanks for the help, and if you need me to explain more, then please ask and I will provide.

Comment: You have to extend that class so that you can access the data members of the extended class. @juiceb0xk

Comment: Hmm, that is an interesting concept. However, my other class is already extending a JFrame, I cannot find a way to extend a JFrame and the other class at the same time.

Comment: @juiceb0xk What's the [big picture](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here? It seems highly dubious that you would want to access the index of a for loop from another class, in the middle of the for loop. What do you hope to achieve with that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just passing the integer to another class, you can pass the object reference directly to your another class.

```
MyAnotherClass obj = new MyAnotherClass();
for (row = 0; row < myEntries.size(); row++) {
    obj.performSomething(myEntries.get(row));
}
```

And in your other class, you can simple use that object reference directly like below.

```
void performSomething(MyEntry myEntry) {
    System.out.println(myEntry.toString());
}
```

---

Edit: You can rewrite the first for loop using enhanced for loop like below.

```
MyAnotherClass obj = new MyAnotherClass();
for (MyEntry myEntry : myEntries) {
    obj.performSomething(myEntry);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create an object from the class includes "row" variable, inside to the other class. This should do your work:

```
class myMainClass {

    ArrayList<Integer> myEntries = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myOtherClass obj = new myOtherClass();
        // Continue doing your stuff here with obj, like calling obj.f()
        //
        System.out.println(myEntries.get(obj.row).toString());
    }
}

class myOtherClass {

    int row;

    public void f() {
        for (row = 0; row < myEntries.size(); row++) {
            //Other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your constraints are right ,you can create an object for your first class in second class and iterate over data-members and methods of your first class.

Comment: I wouldn't have the slightest on how to achieve this, sorry. I'm only quite new to Java.